# Orphan users/application users

Tags: sql-server

How an orphan user can be an application user at the same time?

If I delete an orphan user at database level, how can I affect his access at application level?

Comment: Are you referring to an application user who is a login or a user that an application (such as a c# program) uses to access a database? An orphan user is typically means that a SQL Server database user and SQL Server login at the instance level (while they share a name) don't refer to each other.

Comment: Both?...I mean, I understand that an orphan user is useless to connect to a database, because there is no login, but maybe It was created as a role. But if not, how can I access to the database eather way? Sorry if I can't be more clear about it, but my english is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of `Orphan User` is a bit different than what you have explained.

An Orphan User in a database is a user which isn't mapped to a login. Usually it happens when we move databases across servers or you delete a login without deleting all the users mapped to that login.

Say on `ServerA` you took a backup of `DatabaseA` which has a `UserA` with `LoginA`.

Now you restored this backup on `ServerB` which also has a login `LoginA`. when you restore the database on `ServerB` the `UserA` will become an Orphan User and you will fix it by executing the following command:

```
ALTER USER [UserA] WITH LOGIN = [UserA];
```

This will map the `UserA` to `LoginA` on `ServerB`.And if you do not fix this whether it be your application or anything who uses this UserA's credentials will not be able to access the Database on ServerB.

Comment: Thank you. So, If I'm using VB, C# or any other application like those, I cannot be able to connect to my database because I don't have login mapped to that user....I'm I correct?? So, that user is useless. But what if I'm using an end user application? same result? thank you again.